# Why is blender treating vertices differently when applying subdivision surface modifier?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

[image: The differently treated vertices]

I applied subdivision surface modifier to my model and afterwards, I found some annoying burrs on the surface. Taking a closer look revealed that these burrs are caused by vertices - the surface is kind of snapped to these vertices instead of going smoothly.

I have pretty just begun learning Blender so can neither explain or solve this problem. Please help.

P.S. Most vertices have surface goes smoothly under them.

Comment: Selected vertices are slightly offset, but when you deselect them they're back to normal.

Comment: Doubled checked for duplicates, result is negative. Only one vertex there. As for selecting, unfortunately it is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep it simple:

If the faces normals are in the same orientation, they can be smoothly interpolated at the subdivision: their mean stays positive.

[image]

If they are not, their mean becomes null and so their is no interpolation possible and their mean (so the orientation) is null.

[image]

This is like to say the function is not derivable at the face junction.

So the junction stays a singularity and stays angular.

Answer (score 1):

Though totally have no idea why, after selecting all the vertices (thus all the faces) and recalculating their normal (ctrl + shift + N), the problem is solved.

However, answers explaining reasons will still be appreciated.

Comment: Normals give orientation to the calculation. If normals are opposite on each side of an edge, that lead to angular result, if in the same orientation, smooth result.